# Siteminder root resource rule

Tags: iis-7, siteminder

I have a ASP.NET MVC Web Site running with Siteminder SOO.
Al security is working correctly, except the Home Page.

In the SiteMinder configuration i have only one Realm with Resource Filter: "/" and Default Resource Protection: "Protected". So, all uris are protected. And i have rules for each uri, and a set of Domain Policies that works fine with these rules. The problem is the root page; i don't know how to write a Rule that allow access to the home page, for example:  "http://misite.com/".

If I create a Rule with resource = "/", then the Effective Resource is: "my-siteminder-agent//". And a policy with this rule never applies.

¿How can i create a Rule to allow access to the home page for authenticated users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using a Rule on SiteMinder to allow Access to '/Home' and a redirect with the IIS Rewrite Module.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Root Hit Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^$" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="/Home" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also create a unprotected rule to allow the specific home page... ie index.htm

Comment: I can't because i don't have a specific "index.htm" page to made an unprotected rule.

Answer (score 1):

Change the rule to * instead of /*

Answer (score 0):

If the entire site needs to be secured you do not need to create multiple rules for different paths. A standard rule covering everything will be sufficient. Refer to the Answer by @bcarroll to set that up. It will make your life easier when you have to make changes to the policies etc. later.